# How to toggle a checkbox when clicking in a row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle the checked property of a checkbox when I click on a table row but so far with my solution I am unable to achieve it. This is how the HTML looks like:

```
<table id="chkContainer">
  <tr id="row-1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>1st Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-2">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>2nd Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-3">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>3rd Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the jQuery code I have built:

```
$(function() {
  $("#chkContainer tr > td").on("click", function() {
    const tr = $(this).closest('tr')
    const chk = tr.find('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);

    tr.toggleClass('red', chk.checked);
  })
})
```

What is not working? I can check the checkbox when clicking the row for the first time but when I click the same row once again the checkbox remains checked. I am pretty sure my issue is this line: `$(":checkbox[value=" + id + "]").prop("checked", true)` since I am always setting it to `true` but I am not sure how to set it to `false` when the same row gets a new click.

How do I avoid this behavior from happening if I click in the last td which generally contains buttons or user actions?

I could not find any solution to this or I am very bad at searching on Google :|

here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/f40p9uav/2/) so you can play with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing jQuery with vanilla.

`chk.checked` would be vanilla JS but `chk` is jQuery object. Use jQuery's `chk.is(':checked');`

Best practice is to prepend jQuery objects with $ so you don't get mixed up. i.e. this is not ambiguous

```
const chk  = document.querySelector('.somecheckbox');
const $chk = $('.somecheckbox');
```

Also you're going to have an issue, once it works, when you check the actual checkbox, because the logic will toggle twice since you checked the box manually and the click propagates to the tr which then toggles it programmatically. We need the click to propagate in this case because clicking the tr triggers a colour change too, but we can work around it.

To have the last td not click, you can ignore that, just as you ignore clicking on the checkbox by using `e.target` to know exactly what the clicked element is. The target is the clicked element, but your selector selects a td. The click event bubbles up (unless told not to) from any child of the td, which is why the target may not be the selector.

**Important: Checking it's not the last td isn't enough; you also need to check that the target isn't a child of that non-clickable td.**

[The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykc32w5g/1/)

```js
$(function() {
    $("#chkContainer tr > td").on("click", function(e) {
        // store the td, we're using it to check that it's not the last one in the row later
        const $td = $(this);
        const $tr = $td.closest('tr');
        const $chk = $tr.find('input:checkbox');
    
        if ( !$(e.target).is($chk) && !$td.is(':last-child') ){
          $chk.prop("checked", !$chk.is(':checked'));
       }
       $tr.toggleClass('red', $chk.is(':checked'));
    });
})
```

```css
td{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="chkContainer">
  <tr id="row-1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>1st Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-2">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>2nd Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-3">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>3rd Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable <button>
    I'm a child element of the not-clickable td
    </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: while this answer is great is missing a small piece from the OP: "How do I avoid this behavior from happening if I click in the last td which generally contains buttons or user actions?" this means if I click on the last TD in a row the checkbox should remain uncheck and the row should not be highlighted

Comment: @ReynierPM Thanks I missed that line and will update the answer. While other people who answered else did notice that, they didn't account for clicking a child element in that not-clickable td.

Answer (score 1):

when the user clicks on the checkbox, it switches its state.
but in doing so it also clicks on a td element, which you have programmed to force the checkbox to true.

```js
const tb_chkContainer = document.querySelector('#chkContainer')

tb_chkContainer.addEventListener('click', (evt) =>
  {
  let tr    = evt.target.closest('tr')
    , chkBx = tr.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]')
    ;
  if (evt.target.matches('td'))  // only <td> (not checkbox element)
    {
    chkBx.checked = !chkBx.checked; // switch checkbox value
    }
  tr.classList.toggle('red', chkBx.checked );
  })
```

```css
.red {
  background : red;
  }
```

```html
<table id="chkContainer">
  <tr id="row-1">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td>1st Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-2">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td>2nd Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-3">
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
    <td>3rd Row</td>
    <td>Not clickable</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

-> you can use prop() function with callback to toggle checked based on its current state.

-> modified jQuery Code :-

```
$(function() {
  $("#chkContainer tr > td").on("click", function(event) {
    // Check if the clicked td is not the last one (containing buttons or actions)
    if (!$(event.target).is('td:last-child')) {
      const tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      const chk = tr.find('input:checkbox');

      // Toggle the checked property of the checkbox
      chk.prop("checked", !chk.prop("checked"));

      tr.toggleClass('red', chk.prop("checked"));
    }
  });
});
```

-> in this code, clicking on table row toggles checked property of the checkbox in that row. if you click on the last 'td' of row,its won't toggle checkbox.

-> try my code.